# Can not create table with simple sql code

Tags: sqlite, dart

I get an error

```
E/SQLiteLog( 3975): (1) near "TEXT": syntax error
I/flutter ( 3975): error DatabaseException(near "TEXT": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE Expense (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,amount REAL,date TEXT,category TEXT) sql 'CREATE TABLE Expense (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,amount REAL,date TEXT,category TEXT' args []} during open, closing...
E/flutter ( 3975): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(near "TEXT": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE Expense (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,amount REAL,date TEXT,category TEXT) sql 'CREATE TABLE Expense (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,amount REAL,date TEXT,category TEXT' args []}
```

on this code

```
 initDB() async {
    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, "ExpenseDB2.db");
    return await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onOpen: (db) {},
        onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
      await db.execute("CREATE TABLE Expense (" //the error is on this line
          "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
          "amount REAL,"
          "date TEXT,"
          "category TEXT");
```

What is wrong with it?

Comment: Missing a close `)` after `category TEXT`?

Comment: @DinoCoderSaurus thanks